# WicketTester how to get html output for component?

Tags: html, wicket, wicket-tester, wicket-6

I want to check if a given component has a CSS class set. To do this, I would like to get the HTML output for just that specific component.

WicketTester can provide the HTML output for the entire rendered page. What would be the best approach to get just the Component's HTML/String output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> To do this, I would like to get the HTML output for just that specific
>   component.

Instead of making your assertions on the HTML output, you could use TagTester to test the CSS classes like this:

```
WicketTester tester = new WicketTester(new WicketApplication());
tester.startPage(MyPage.class);
TagTester tagTester = tester.getTagByWicketId("myWicketComponent");
Assert.assertEquals("classA classB", tagTester.getAttribute("class"));
```

Try if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the TagTester class. It look promising for my particular problem.